# Should the routing table only be applied to outgoing packets (not forwarding)?

Tags: networking, routing, netfilter

I am trying to get packets forwarded from device A to device C, through device B. I thought all I have to do is on device A say: packets for C must go to B, and then B knows where where C is so all should be good...

however, this does not work. I have checked that `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` and `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward = 1`. I also set `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0`. I also just in case set the same for the specific devices.

#### To give an example:

device A = 192.168.10.1/24
device B eth0 = 192.168.10.2/24

device B eth1 = 192.168.11.1/24
device C = 192.168.11.2/24

Now all the devices have routes for the basic subnets they need, e.g. device B:
`192.168.10.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.2`
`192.168.11.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.11.1`

And in theory, I thought all I needed was to say on device A:
`sudo ip route add 192.168.11.0/24 via 192.168.10.2`

But it doesn't work
Now the weirdest thing of all is I can ping from A to 192.168.11.1 yes. but not to 192.168.11.2? How is it possible that it can get to a device on the subnet but then not to the other addresses on the subnet?

#### the routing table is not applying to incoming packets?

https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Netfilter_hooks
On this diagram, it shows 2 routing decisions, one before the input chain and one before the output chain. It seems that the routing table (shown with command ip route) only applies to the decision before the output chain. Because if I ping 192.168.11.2 from device B, it can find it.

My main question is, is this expected?

Comment: Just to verify, you have ip_forward=1 set on B (and not e.g. only on A)? Also check that your firewall rules allow forwarding (the `FORWARD` chain in iptables)

Comment: For a ping to work, packets need to travel in both directions. Did you configure C to route A's packets through B aswell?

Comment: The ping to an address of B doesn't count as forwarding, so can't be used for validation. Either B doesn't forward, or B has a firewall preventing forwarding.

Answer (score -1):

Reproducing the setup on a fresh image of the board works in the expected way. Despite net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 the packets were not being forwarded.

Still don't know exactly why but image is not very stable on the dev board being used.